# Post tumblr api forbidden

Tags: php, laravel, api, tumblr

I need to make a post in tumblr using the tumblr api.

Using the official [tumblr php wrapper](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php) is not working, if i do a post method. When doing a get method it works fine i will get all the information i need.

I commented the get method. So you have a idea

```
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $tumblrId = $request->get('tumblr_id');
        $table = DB::table('tumblr_tables')->where('id', $tumblrId);
        $blogName = $request->get('title');
        $body = $request->get('body');
        $createdAt= $request->get('created_at');
        $consumerKey = $table->value('consumer_key');
        $consumerSecret = $table->value('consumer_secret');
        $consumerToken= $table->value('tumblr_token');
        $tumblrSecret = $table->value('tumblr_secret');

        $data = [$body, $createdAt];

        // Authenticate via OAuth
        $client = new Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
        $client->setToken($consumerToken, $tumblrSecret);
//        foreach ($client->getUserInfo()->user->blogs as $blog) {
//            echo $blog->name . "\n";
//        }

        $client->createPost($blogName, $data);

//        return response(redirect(route('voyager.posts.index'))->with(['message' => "Your post created", 'alert-type' => 'success']));
        return response('hello world');

    }
```

I expect to see a new post on my tumblr page

Comment: Where does `$blogName` and `$data` come from? What is their value? What is the `createPost()` function? Is that part of the tumblr PHP wrapper? Do you get an error code? What error code? What is your question?

Comment: no i have them declared in the same function, yes createpost is part of the wrapper

Comment: Well that answers 1-2 of my questions...

Comment: We can assume that all of the code you have actually shown us is correct, because `getUserInfo()` works, but we have no way of knowing if `createPost()` will work because we don't know what the value of the variables are.

Comment: just edited the code to clarify

Comment: Your update is a step in the right direction, however, it's still not enough information. We have no way of knowing what the value of `$request->get('title')` is, and we don't know what the value of `$request->get('body')` is, and `$createdAt` is never defined.

Comment: Now you have everything^^

Comment: Sorry, but no, we still have nothing. There is no way for us to know the values of `$blogName`, `$body` OR `$createdAt`, because the values are hidden behind function calls. We don't know what these variables contain (or what these functions return), because we don't know how your overall application works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197390/discussion-between-di477-and-grumpycrouton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GrumpyCrouton

$blogName should be the name of the blog you are posting to

$client->createPost($blogName, $data);